# Ansible and jinja - Sending double-quote escaped JSON string into AWS

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

We need to provide a double-quote escaped JSON string into AWS secrets for a nodeJS product. Single-within-double quoted format will not work with the application. The structured data is in dict-list-dict format. Example:

```
{
  "data": "[{\"URL\": \"beta.test.net\", \"token\": \"beta-token\"}, {\"URL\": \"beta-prod.test.net\", \"token\": \"beta-prod-token\"}]"
}
```

I tried a number of filters to get ansible and jinja to take the JSON variable and convert it to a string in the format wanted, but results are never quite right. | to_json | string gives the following result:

```
{
  "data": "[{'URL': 'beta.test.net', 'token': 'beta-token'}, {'token': 'test-token', 'URL': 'beta-prod.test.net'}]"
}
```

And when I try using replace or regex replace, it appears that even with a guard character I end up hitting a python parsing error. Here's an example just using a replace with a grave's accent '`' escape.

```
TASK [Update secret in AWS] ***************************************************************************************************
task path: path:27
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 146, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 587, in _execute
    self._task.post_validate(templar=templar)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/playbook/task.py", line 296, in post_validate
    super(Task, self).post_validate(templar)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/playbook/base.py", line 431, in post_validate
    value = templar.template(getattr(self, name))
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 623, in template
    disable_lookups=disable_lookups,
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 578, in template
    disable_lookups=disable_lookups,
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 806, in do_template
    data = _escape_backslashes(data, myenv)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 149, in _escape_backslashes
    for token in jinja_env.lex(d2):
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/lexer.py", line 739, in tokeniter
    name, filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '`' at 51
  line 1
fatal: [beta-prod]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

Using regex replace I can get all the way to removing the single quotes and replacing it with a '\', but any attempt to add '\"' will always fail with the above parsing error.

Here's the ansible code calling AWS secrets with a few of my attempts to provide the correct format:

```
    - name: Update secret in AWS
      aws_secret:
        name: '{{ aws_secret_name }}'
        state: present
        secret_type: 'string'
 #       secret: "{{ token_list_update | to_json | replace(\"'\",\"\") | string }}"
        secret: '{{ token_list_update | to_json | string }}'
   #     secret: ' {"data": "{{ token_list | to_json | regex_replace(`"`,`\\"`) }}"}'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm getting the idea I made need to write my own filter to handle this. I did ask if the application would accept single-within-double-quoted JSON string, but the team indicated this was not acceptable. The format must be a double-quote escaped JSON string.

Final Edit:

After a few more days of work, figured this one out. At each step you need to cast the correct type to preserve JSON formatting. When doing updates each list element needs to be filtered to_json. Example:

```
  token_list: "{{ (token_list | default([]) + [_update]) | to_json }}"
```

_update is a helper variable that is a JMESPath search

The final submission into AWS:

```
    - name: Update secret in AWS
      aws_secret:
        name: "{{ aws_secret_name }}"
        state: present
        secret_type: "string"
        secret: "{\"data\":{{ token_list | to_json}}}"
```

Comment: `token_list_update` this value would be what ?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you posted the error you're getting without the use of non-JSON characters (such as the backtick); I suspect ansible is doing the right thing, but the default stdout callback packaging the message in JSON itself may be confusing if you're not used to it. Further down that trail, are you certain that `secret: "{{ token_list_update | to_json }}"` didn't do what you wanted? Did you check in AWS to see if the item was stored as you expected?

Comment: `token_list_update` is the dict-list-dict native object. Sorry I didn't clarify that. `"{{ token_list_update | to_json }}"` stores the incorrect value in AWS - `{
  "data": "[{'URL': 'beta.test.net', 'token': 'beta-token'}, {'token': 'test-token', 'URL': 'beta-prod.test.net'}]"
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little long but this should get you what you need.

**playbook**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: get string
      shell: "python3.7 print-string.py"
      register: json_string
    - name: Update secret in AWS
      aws_secret:
        name: 'testing/json_string'
        state: present
        secret_type: 'string'
        secret: "{{ json_string['stdout'] | string }}"
```

**print-string.py**

```py
import json

data = {
      "data": "[{'URL': 'beta.test.net', 'token': 'beta-token'}, {'token': 'beta-prod-token', 'URL': 'beta-prod.test.net'}]"
    }

print(json.dumps(data).replace('[{\'', '[{\\"').replace('\': \'', '\\": \\"').replace('\'', '\\"'))
```

will produce:

```
{
  "data": "[{\"URL\": \"beta.test.net\", \"token\": \"beta-token\"}, {\"token\": \"beta-prod-token\", \"URL\": \"beta-prod.test.net\"}]"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, Danny! Unfortunately we cannot shell out, however, I did find a solution, which I am updating now

Comment: I tested this, and it appears ansible converted it:
`[WARNING]: The value <stripped> (type dict) in a string field was converted to <stripped> (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change.`

Comment: Check the secret in AWS. I updated my post and put a picture of what was put into AWS Secrets Manager.

Comment: let me know what you come up with.

Comment: Our developer got the same result, it's related to the string you are using as the source. That format works, but our source is this string:
`{
  "data": "[{\"URL\": \"beta.test.net\", \"token\": \"beta-token\"}, {\"URL\": \"beta-prod.test.net\", \"token\": \"beta-prod-token\"}]"
}`
The quoting of the source seems to make a difference - Either way, will update once I have a solution

Answer (score 7):

with a native jinja2 filter: `tojson`

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#tojson

I am using it like:

toto.json.j2:

```
{"hello" : "world"}
```

```
{{ lookup('template', './toto.json.j2') | to_json | tojson }}
```

This generate:

```
"{\"hello\" : \"world\"}"
```

Comment: Hello, i like this method, but it see new quotes around the list, how can we remove it

Comment: this is normal, this is a string. Dont know how to remove it, maybe with a substring filter